# Django - ModelForm - Filter by user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I need to filter in `EmployeeForm` just to show me options of Companies related to user is logged in. I'm using ModelForm and CreateViews

This is my code:

`models.py:`

```
class Company(models.Model):
    reg_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cuit = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Employee(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Empresa, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cuil = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

`forms.py:`

```
class EmployeeForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ...
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['autofocus'] = True
```

What is the code I need to write in the ellipses? It's currently showing me all companies even ones not owned by the user.

Answer (score 2):

I use `forms.Form` for this instead of `ModelForm`, but what i do is:

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.Form):
    companies = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None)

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['companies'].queryset = Company.objects.filter(reg_user=user)
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally could solve this by using this in views.py

```
def get_form(self):
        form = super(EmployeeCreateView, self).get_form()
        form.fields['company'].queryset = Company.objects.filter(reg_user=self.request.user)
        return form
```

Thanks for everyone!